# How to run multiple query in Codeigniter that are separated by semicolon

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have an attendance table and i want to insert data in it if not exits and update if exist, query in Loop working fine but take too much time. So to reduce time i concatenate  all  query as string separated by semicolon. The result get after concatenation work in phpMyAdmin but not in Codeigniter,
any guess Why? 
Thanks in advance.

```
function set_attendance()
    {
        $today = date('Y-m-d');
        $data = $this->input->post('member');
        $str='';
        foreach ($data as  $value) 
        {
            $query = $this->db->select('*')
                            ->from('attendance')
                            ->where('user_id',$value['user_id'])
                            ->where('date',$today)
                            ->get();

            if($query->num_rows()>0)
            {
                $obj = array(
                       'attendance'    => $value['status'],
                       'leavetype' => $value['leavetype'],
                );

                $where = "user_id =  '{$value['user_id']}' AND date = '{$today}'";

                $str .= $this->db->update_string('attendance', $obj, $where);
                $str.=';';
            }
            else
            {
                 $obj = array(
                        's-no'  => null,
                        'user_id' => $value['user_id'],
                        'date' => $today,
                        'regby'=>'t',
                        'leavetype' => $value['leavetype'],
                       'attendance'    => $value['status'],
                );
                $str .= $this->db->insert_string('attendance', $obj);
                 $str.=';';

            }

        }

        $this->db->query($str);
        $output = array('result'=>true);
        return $output ;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `$this->db->insert_batch()` ? see https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data

Answer (score 0):

Ok I get answer
Just run php native multi_query() function

```
function set_attendance()
    {
        $today = date('Y-m-d');
        $data = $this->input->post('member');
        $str='';
        foreach ($data as  $value) 
        {
            $query = $this->db->select('*')
                            ->from('attendance')
                            ->where('user_id',$value['user_id'])
                            ->where('date',$today)
                            ->get();

            if($query->num_rows()>0)
            {
                $obj = array(
                       'attendance'    => $value['status'],
                       'leavetype' => $value['leavetype'],
                );

                $where = "user_id =  '{$value['user_id']}' AND date = '{$today}'";

                $str .= $this->db->update_string('attendance', $obj, $where);
                $str.=';';
            }
            else
            {
                 $obj = array(
                        's-no'  => null,
                        'user_id' => $value['user_id'],
                        'date' => $today,
                        'regby'=>'t',
                        'leavetype' => $value['leavetype'],
                       'attendance'    => $value['status'],
                );
                $str .= $this->db->insert_string('attendance', $obj);
                 $str.=';';

            }

        }
        $link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','yoga_panel');
        if(mysqli_multi_query($link,$str))
        {
            $output=array('result'=>true);
            return $output;
        } 
    }
```